# How can I sort Recyclerview items by if app is installed on device or not

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview, collections

I have a list of apps which you can access via google play. for any app I have a JSON array like this;

```
{
  "packageName": "com.whatsapp",
  "name": "WhatsApp",
  "iconUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/bYtqbOcTYOlgc6gqZ2rwb8lptHuwlNE75zYJu6Bn076-hTmvd96HH-6v7S0YUAAJXoJN\u003ds180",
  "price": "0",
  "ratingValue": 4.3,
  "ratingCount": 107579089,
  "downloads": "5,000,000,000+",
  "publishDate": {
    "year": 2020,
    "month": 3,
    "day": 18
  },
  "version": "2.20.89",
  "category": "COMMUNICATION",
  "developerName": "WhatsApp Inc.",
  "developerEmail": "android@support.whatsapp.com",
  "developerAddress": "1601 Willow Road Menlo Park, CA 94025"
}
```

I can sort the app by names in recyclerview, it is in Utils class and it works well;

```
 public static void sortByName(List<AppModel> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
}
```

Moreover via my AppModel class I can retrieve packagaName for each app,
I want to sort these apps if it is installed on device or not, namely, if there are 20 apps and if I have installed 3 of them I want to show firstly these 3 apps in recyclerview.

I tried this method, but it didn't work;

```
 private static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}



public static void sortByDeviceInstallation(Context context, List<AppModel> list) {

    List<AppModel> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AppModel> otherApps = new ArrayList<>();

    for (AppModel app : list) {
        if (isAppInstalled(context, app.getPackageName())) {
            installedApps.add(app);
        } else {
            otherApps.add(app);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(installedApps, (o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));

    Collections.sort(otherApps, (o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));

    installedApps.addAll(otherApps);
}
```

and used in my fragment;

```
SortData.sortByDeviceInstallation(getActivity(), list);
```

Comment: Okay so you first want to sort list on the basis of installation, and then on the basis of application name?

Comment: yes, right  Heisenberg, I added the method I tried

Comment: You just have to work with two lists, first one contain installed applications and second contains applications that is not installed. Then sort both list on the basis of app-name, then concat list2 over list1.

Comment: which method should I use for sorting installed apps? Heisenberg

Comment: You can sort both list via comparator, as you were using. Is your comparator working for sorting json list?

Comment: yes it works, I can sort by name, downloads and ratings, I wrote I new method, I just edit it but unfortunately it didn't work Heisenberg